# I want to generate the gatling html file by using simulation.log file

Tags: performance, karate

I have a long running test which runs for 5 days, but it has run only for 3 days. Before 5 days, gatling test is aborted.

Now I want to generate my gatling report based on simulation.log file. Can anyone please let us know the command to generate report?

I am running my test from terminal in intellijIDEA.

Comment: please refer to the other question and the gatling docs if needed

Comment: Thanks Peter. I was able to generate the report based on simulation.log file.